# Auto SVN update inside server for website management

Tags: svn, version-control

**I would like to know how to automatically perform and SVN update on a external server once that it detects that new code has been commited.**

I'm more or less new to revision control software like SVN and setted up a SVN repository on htdocs expecting that when I did a commit on my desktop computer the changes would be updated on the server and the webpage would be updated. However SVN stores the files in a database (they are not visible on the repository folder) so what I have to do to view the changes on the website is to perform a local checkout on the server from the repository to the htdocs folders...

**How could I perform an svn auto update on the server?** I know that this would be troublesome if many users try to commit changes, but I'm more interested in the "versioning features" rather than the "multiple users collaboration feature".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put in place on your server a cron job that just runs an update every hour or every midnight but better would be either to change your workflow so as to use a batch file or script to perform your commits or best of all yet put a post commit hook in place that does a checkout on your server whenever there is a new commit, or even a new commit from a specific user, e.g. You or a Release Manager.  You could also set up a full blown SVN web sever - this is probably more work than you need unless you are letting a lot of people have SVN access to your working environment via the web.

See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks) for some examples of hooks.

So your options are:

1. Automatically get any updates every x time - easy to do but the web site will be out of date until up to x time has elapsed.
2. Use a different commit method - also easy **but** will only work for those that use the new method.
3. Use post commit hooks - *best of all works for everybody and always updates on successful commit but never in between*.
4. Full Blown Web Server - lots of work!

### Added hook details from OP

> Many thanks for the quick response Steves! Confirmed option 3 works
>   very well, to enrich the answer even more, if someone else wants to do
>   the same, this is the code that I used on "post-commit" hook (note the
>   no extension):

```
#!/bin/sh sudo svn update [path to working copy] >> [path to log]
```

> The >> [path to log] is optional of course. Also the file post-commit
>   was converted to file permission 755. – Alejandro del Río

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response Steves! Confirmed option 3 works very well, to enrich the answer even more, if someone else wants to do the same, this is the code that I used on "post-commit" hook (note the no extension):


#!/bin/sh
sudo svn update [path to working copy] >> [path to log]


The >> [path to log] is optional of course. Also the file post-commit was converted to file permission 755.

Comment: My pleasure @AlejandrodelRío - glad to have helped.